# Transformation of random variable using CDF not making sense?

Tags: probability, random-variables, transformation, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have two exponential random variables $X,Y$ that are both identical (i.e. they have the same $\lambda$).
I am attempting to find their sum using the method of CDFs (please note, I understand how to use the convolution but this is for completeness).

We have $f_X(x) = f_Y(y) =  \begin{cases} 
      \lambda e^{-\lambda x} & x \ge 0 \\
      0 & elsewhere 
   \end{cases}$

The transformation we are given is $U = X+Y$.

Because $f_X(x) = f_Y(y)$, I propose we may treat this transformation as $U=2X$.

$F_U(u) = P(U\le u) = P(2X \le u) = P(X \le u/2) = F_X(u/2)$.

We know that the CDF of an exponential random variable is given by $F_X(x)=  \begin{cases} 
      1-e^{-\lambda x} & x \ge 0 \\
      0 & elsewhere 
   \end{cases}$

So $F_X(u/2) =\begin{cases} 
      1-e^{-\lambda u/2} & u \ge 0 \\
      0 & elsewhere 
   \end{cases}
$

Taking the derivative, we reach
$f_U(u) = \begin{cases} 
      (\lambda /2)e^{-\lambda u/2} & u \ge 0 \\
      0 & elsewhere 
   \end{cases}$

But, when I solve by convolution I get $f_U(u) = \begin{cases} 
      \lambda ^2ue^{-\lambda u} & u \ge 0 \\
      0 & elsewhere 
   \end{cases}$

So I'm really unsure what's going on, any suggestions?

Comment: You don't have $X+Y=2X$ if they are identically distributed but not literally identical variables. For example if they are independent (which is the case that is handled by convolving the PDFs) then this doesn't happen.

Comment: @Ian I see. The question I am working on did say they were independent too. So the error is assuming that they are the same random variable then?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing by means of density and not by cdf. This is the way to do by cdf.

Let $U=X+Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are iid exponential variates.

$$F_{U}(u)=P(U\leq u)=P(X+Y\leq u)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{X\leq u-y\}})|Y=y))$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{2}e^{-\lambda(x+y)}\mathbf{1}_{\{x\leq u-y,u-y\geq0\}}dxdy\\=\int_{0}^{u}\int_{0}^{u-y}\lambda^{2}e^{-\lambda(x+y)}\,dxdy\\=1-e^{-\lambda u}(1+\lambda u)\,,u\geq 0$$

(I have done this by means of indicators. You can just integrate the joint density over the region $\{x+y\leq u\}\cap[0,\infty)^{2}$ to get the same result)

That is :- $F_{U}(u)=\begin{cases}1-e^{-\lambda u}(1+\lambda u)\,,u\geq 0\\0\,,\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

So the density of $U$ is found by differentiating:-

$$f_{U}(u)=\lambda^{2}ue^{-\lambda u}\,,u\geq 0$$.

So $U\sim\text{Gamma}(2,\lambda)$

There are also other means of doing this. Perhaps the easiest is by Moment Generating Functions or Characteristic function.

The MGF of $X$ and $Y$ is :- $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}$.

So the MGF of $X+Y = \left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}\right)^{2}=\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{t}{\lambda}}\right)^{2}$

Which is the same as that of a $\text{Gamma}(2,\lambda)$ variate. And hence will share the same cdf with it.

More generally the sum of $n$ iid $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ variates is a $\text{Gamma}(n,\lambda)$ variate.

Where $\text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ has the density :-
$\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\beta^{\alpha}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}$

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunatley my current module doesn't go into quite this much depth. I think the nature of the question essentially just demands method of convolution.

Comment: @HungaryGoose Your question was titled deriving using "cdf". That is why I used this method. You are using convolution to derive the pdf and not the cdf. In fact what I am doing is something similar to convolution but for CDFs .

Comment: No I mistakenly thought that because the two variables had the same distribution that they were identical, and hence U=2X. Which is wrong.

Comment: That's not what I am talking about. I am saying that you in your question statement were asking about using the CDF to find the CDF of $X+Y$. But in your efforts  in the convolution method you are just finding the PDF . If you want to derive the CDF directly without the pdf you have to proceed like I did.